# Insert Values into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on inserting values into database. i need to insert products. user can add more than one product on front-end. 
for this i have 2 tables into database.first is tbl_test and second tbl_test_months. In tbl_test i am inserting product name 
and growth rate of products. Products price and sale are going for 12 months. So in 2nd table i need to enter product
id , sales, price according to month. but my product id is not entering in right way. i want after 12 month it should
take 2nd product id.This is my code. Please help me.

```
for($p=0; $p < $countProduct; $p++)
{
    $revInsert= "insert into tbl_test(id, user_id, product_name, price_growth_rate_year1, price_growth_rate_year2, sale_growth_rate_year1, sale_growth_rate_year2, scenario, currency_type, price_raise)
                values('','".$user_id."', '".$productName[$p]."', '".$growth_price_first[$p]."', '".$growth_price_second[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_first[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_second[$p]."', '".$scenario."', '".$pCurrency[$p]."', '".$priceRaiseStatus[$p]."')";
    $QueryRev= mysql_query($revInsert);
    $id= mysql_insert_id();
}
for($q=0; $q<$cnt; $q++)
{  
    $rev_month_insert= "insert into tbl_test_months(id, user_id, product_id, month, year, sale_volume, sale_price, scenario) 
    values('','".$user_id."', '".$id."','".$months1[$q % 12]."', '".$year."', '".$sale_volume1[$q]."', '".$price_currency_contract[$q]."', '".$scenario."')";
    $query= mysql_query($rev_month_insert);
}
```

Comment: For a start, don't use the old mysql library, it is massively outdated. Use mysqli instead.

Comment: Please define 'but my product id is not entering in right way.'. What is it currently inserting and do you think it should insert?

Comment: it insert only 1st product id in all fields i want to insert id for ex. i have prodct1 with is 1 i want to insert 1 for jan to dec 12 months and when loop start again for prodct2 from jan to dec then i want to insert product2 id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the ids in an array and insert them accordingly.Try like this

```
$id_arr = array();
for($p=0; $p < $countProduct; $p++)
{
    $revInsert= "insert into tbl_test(id, user_id, product_name, price_growth_rate_year1, price_growth_rate_year2, sale_growth_rate_year1, sale_growth_rate_year2, scenario, currency_type, price_raise)
                values('','".$user_id."', '".$productName[$p]."', '".$growth_price_first[$p]."', '".$growth_price_second[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_first[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_second[$p]."', '".$scenario."', '".$pCurrency[$p]."', '".$priceRaiseStatus[$p]."')";
    $QueryRev= mysql_query($revInsert);
    $id_arr[] = mysql_insert_id();
}
for($q=0; $q<$cnt; $q++)
{  
    $rev_month_insert= "insert into tbl_test_months(id, user_id, product_id, month, year, sale_volume, sale_price, scenario) 
    values('','".$user_id."', '".$id_arr[$q]."','".$months1[$q % 12]."', '".$year."', '".$sale_volume1[$q]."', '".$price_currency_contract[$q]."', '".$scenario."')";
    $query= mysql_query($rev_month_insert);
}
```

And makesure that you have an `auto increment` field in the `tbl_test` table and Dont use `mysql_*` functions due to they are deprecated.Instead use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements

Comment: now it is showing this error Notice: Undefined offset: 2. it insert product id in first two rows and other empty.

Comment: yes these are diff. $countProduct is count number of product and $cnt is count a product has number of values. like 
a product contain 12 months values. if i add 2 product then there will be 24 entries in 2nd table. 12 for product1
and 12 for 2nd product. I want product id 1 for first 12 entries and  next 12 12 entries product id 2.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

> **Return Values:** The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

I am assuming your `id` column is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the use of `mysql_insert_id`, in which case you don't want to specify `id` in your insert statements.

Even if the column is auto increment you can still supply `id` in your insert query.  But in your case you are supplying `''`.  If this is a primary key column then your insert queries in your first loop should be failing right at index `$p=1` because of duplicate primary key.

Based on what you've provided I think the solution would be the following:

```
for($p=0; $p < $countProduct; $p++)
{
    $revInsert= "insert into tbl_test(user_id, product_name, price_growth_rate_year1, price_growth_rate_year2, sale_growth_rate_year1, sale_growth_rate_year2, scenario, currency_type, price_raise)
                values('".$user_id."', '".$productName[$p]."', '".$growth_price_first[$p]."', '".$growth_price_second[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_first[$p]."', '".$growth_sale_second[$p]."', '".$scenario."', '".$pCurrency[$p]."', '".$priceRaiseStatus[$p]."')";
    $QueryRev= mysql_query($revInsert);
    $product_id= mysql_insert_id();

    for($q=0; $q<$cnt; $q++)
    {  
      $rev_month_insert= "insert into tbl_test_months(user_id, product_id, month, year, sale_volume, sale_price, scenario) 
      values('".$user_id."', '".$product_id."','".$months1[$q % 12]."', '".$year."', '".$sale_volume1[$q]."', '".$price_currency_contract[$q]."', '".$scenario."')";
      $query= mysql_query($rev_month_insert);
    }

    // Update
    unset($product_id);
}
```

Comment: i have more than 2 products. with this it insert product1 id for all products.

Comment: @user1523311, I had a missing leading single quote before `$user_id` in the second query which I've fixed in the code above.  What are `$countProduct` and `$cnt`?  Do you want entries in `tbl_test_months` for each entry in `tbl_test` or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: $countProduct is count number of product and $cnt is count a product has number of values. like 
a product contain 12 months values.

Comment: $countProduct is count number of product and $cnt is count a product has number of values.for ex. 
single product contain 12 values for 12 months.

Comment: So in the code above, for each product at `$p`, 12 `$q` are inserted with product id at `$p`.

Comment: yes if i add 2 products count of $p will be 2 and count of $q will be 24.

Comment: @user1523311, How is `$cnt` being set?  Since you've said it's just a counter, can you do `$cnt = $cnt/$countProduct`?